# Why isn't this mysql query working?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables:

**x_community_invites** :

```
id  community_id    from    to  registered  message seen    accepted    updated
```

and

**x_communities** :

```
id  name    tags    registered  updated
```

With the query:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT x_commmunities.* FROM x_commmunities, x_community_invites WHERE x_community_invites.to = '%s' AND x_community_invites.accepted = '%d'", $id, 1);
```

My problem is that the query I run returns all the fields from the x_communities table.

> Example scenario:
>
> There are 2 communities in the x_communities table:
>
> - id's - 1 and 2  name
> - 1stCommunity and 2ndCommunity
>
> There are 3 community invites in the x_community_invites table:
>
> - All different id's
> - 2 with the same community id as 1st Community, both to fields accepted
> - 1 with the same community id as 2nd Community, to = profile id and accepted = 1
>
> But with the query, it grabs all of the communities ids and names, for
>   some reason unknown to me.

I want to return the community id and name where the x_communities_invites.to field is the user id and the x_communities_invites.accepted field is 1.

Also, what sort of query is the above query? Some sort of join, I can't find a similar query online with similar syntax.

Can you help me out here?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "Also, what sort of query is the above query?" It's a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join), or Cartesian product. Generally, you don't want those unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: thanks for that, I can now stackoverflow/google it! reputation++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't linked tables. You should use JOIN:

```
SELECT x_commmunities.* 
FROM x_commmunities
JOIN x_community_invites  on x_commmunities.id=x_community_invites.community_id
WHERE x_community_invites.to = '%s' AND x_community_invites.accepted = '%d'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an implicit inner join, but the condition that connects the two tables is missing.

```
SELECT x_commmunities.id, x_commmunities.name, COUNT(x_community_invites.*) AS invites
  FROM x_commmunities, x_community_invites 
 WHERE x_commmunities.id = x_community_invites.community_id
   AND x_community_invites.to = 'some_id_value' 
   AND x_community_invites.accepted = '1'
 GROUP BY x_commmunities.id, x_commmunities.name
```

This could result in duplicates (multiple invites for the same community). GROUP BY aggregates the records by the provided fields.

Answer (score 1):

When using `FROM x_commmunities, x_community_invites` you are doing a cross-join that combines every row of `x_communities` with every row from `x_community_invites` without doing any matching at all.

You have add some separate join-constraint to tell the DBMS how to find matching pairs:

```
WHERE x_communities.id = x_community_invites.community_id
```

This way you will get an inner join.

You could also use join-syntax in your from-clause:

```
FROM x_communities join x_community_invites on(x_communities.id = x_community_invites.community_id)
```

or if you want a outer join:

```
FROM x_communities left join x_community_invites on(x_communities.id = x_community_invites.community_id)
```